# Proof collecting: A short proof of chage of variable formula

Tags: soft-question, change-of-variable

I've been searching for a  proof of the change-of-variable formula for multi-variable Riemann integration, but most of them seem to be too long and cumbersome. I'd like to see one proof that uses clever approximation skills or some advanced techniques, and of course,the shorter, the better.  Thanks in advance :).

By the way, any proof that involves  interesting ideas are also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change of formula reads 
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b}f(\varphi(x))\varphi'(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(u)du,
\end{align*}
say, for $\varphi'>0$ sufficiently good.

1) Using integration by parts, one can do it for $f(x)=x^{n}$, $n=0,1,2,...$

2) Using Stone-Weierstrass, the formula holds for continuous functions $f$.

3) Using the fact that $C[a,b]$ is $L^{1}$ dense in $R[a,b]$, the space of Riemann integrable functions, the result follows.

Comment: Good answer, and how about the multi-variable integration? Do We have an analog of Stone-Weierstrass's theorem?

Comment: Then try to use Fubini to reduce the multiple integrals to the iterated one-dimensional case.

Comment: I see, thanks. Sounds like the proof in Zorich's mathematical analysis.

Comment: Really? But as I remember Zorich's proof does not go over Stone theorem, anyway, my proof may contain some inaccuracy.

Comment: I mean using Fubini to prove high-dimensional case. Zorich just decompose a diffeomorphism into the composition of some simple one-dimensional diffeomorphisms, and then use Fubini.

Comment: I do not see any way to get it from Fubini. How do you compute Jacobian along slices in terms of the full Jacobian. @painday But you do not know the change of variables for those simple diffeomorphisms, do you?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli:Actually, the simple diffeomorphisms used in Zorich's proof are of the form that they only change one coordinate, and leave the other coordinates unchanged. So the change of variable theorem for these simple diffeomorphisms follows immediately from Fubini's theorem and the change of variable formula for one-dimensional integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you asked for ideas, one interesting derivation of change of variables is from Radon-Nikodyn theorem about derivative of measures. First, let us state a precise formulation.
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. If $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable, 1-to-1, and $\det Df(x) \neq 0$ for any $x \in U$, then for any integrable $w:f(U) \to \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\int_{f(U)} w(y) \, d\mathcal{L}^n(y) = \int_U w(f(x)) \, |\det Df(x)| d\mathcal{L}^n(x)\, . \qquad \text{(C.of.V. 1)}
$$

**Proof Sketch:**

1. It suffices to prove C.of.V for characteristic functions of measurable sets, i.e. for any measurable $E\subset U$,
   $$
   \mathcal{L}^n({f(E)}) = \int_E |\det Df(x)| \, d\mathcal{L}^n(x)\, . \qquad \text{(C.of.V. 2)}
   $$
   Then the general case c.of.V. 1 follows from approximation by characteristic functions.
2. I will assume $U=\mathbb{R}^n$ for simplicity. Define a new measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by
   $$
   \mu(E):=\mathcal{L}^n({f(E)}) \, .
   $$
3. Show stuff about this measure. Like it is well-defined, Borel, etc. You'll probably will also need to show $f(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable iff $E$ is.

3.5) Prove that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mathcal{L}^n$, i.e. if $\mathcal{L}^n({E})=0$ then $\mu(E)=0$.

4. Next compute the Radon-Nikodyn derivative:
   $$
   \frac{d\mu}{d\mathcal{L}^n}(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\mu(f(B(x,r))}{\mathcal{L}^n(B(x,r))} = |\det Df(x)| \, .
   $$
   This follows from approximating $f(B(x,r))$ by $Df(x)(B(x,r))$. The approximation comes from differentiability of $f$, and gets arbitrarily close as $r\to 0$. since $Df(x)$ is a linear map, even before having $r\to 0$, we have $\mathcal{L}^n(Df(x)(B(x,r))) = |\det Df(x)|\mathcal{L}^n(B(x,r))$.
5. By Radon-Nikodyn, for every $\mathcal{L}^n$-measurable $E$,
   $$
   \mu(E) = \int_E \frac{d\mu}{d\mathcal{L}^n}(x) \, d\mathcal{L}^n(x) = \int_E |\det Df(x)| \, d\mathcal{L}^n(x),
   $$
   Which is just C.of.V 2.

Apparently this is done in Rudin's book, but I do not have access to them to verify this! Will hopefully update once I find out.

Note: As one matures in math, what is elementary, easy, natural, elegant, etc keeps changing. So, feel free to criticize this proof! :)